# Inserting large csv files into a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, csv

We have an application on the web that must allow the user to upload files with zip codes, these files are .csv's files. Any user will be able to upload the file from their computer, the issue is that the file may contain thousands of records. Right now i am getting the file, making sure it has the right headers but I am pushing the records one by one into the database.

I am using c# asp.net, is there a better way to do this?, more efficient from the code?. We cant use any external importers or data importers or tools like sql server business intelligence. How can I do this?, i was reading something about putting it in memory and then push it to the database?. Any urls, examples or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'm pretty sure that what you are asking is actually *"How do you process a large file and insert the processed data into the database?"*.

Now assuming I am correct I would say the question is akin to 'how long is a piece of string?'. The reality is that an implementation for processing large files into a database is highly specific to your requirements.

However, at the simplest end of the spectrum you could simply upload the file straight into a table (or folder) and create a [windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that runs every x minutes, traverses through the table, picks each file and processes your data using bulk inserts and the [prepare method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx) (which may give you some performance benefits).

Alternatively you could look at something like [MSMQ (Microsoft Message Queuing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) and save any uploaded files direct to a queue which is then completely independent of your application and can be processed at any point in time along with easily scaled out.

At the end of the day though, honestly I don't think anyone here can give you a 'correct' answer to your question cause there really isn't one and you'll only be able to find improvements to your implementation by experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

if this contains up to a million record, best to do this is to create a service to manage the inserting of records into the database to avoid timeout and prevent the web iis stress.

if you make it a windows service you can notify the service to process the zip files in certain directory where it was uploaded.

also, i would suggest to use bulk insert for more faster database transactions.

if there are validation you can probably stage the data into a different database and validate the data then push to the final database.

Answer (score 1):

Since these records are in the same table and would then not be related to each other, [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) may be a valid answer here.  Assuming you have a static method (may not necessarily need to be static) that inserts an individual record into the db, you can run [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) loop over an array where each index of the array represents a line of the CSV.

This assumes that uploading the large file to the server isn't the initial issue.  If that is also part of the issue I would reccomend zipping the file and then using something like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to unzip it once it is uploaded.  Since text compresses very well this may be the biggest boon to performance from the user's perspective.